# Spoofing IP to get content from website?

Tags: websites, ip-spoofing, whitelist

A website is returning valid response if IP of the client is in specific range(whitelist). I know that one can spoof IP within that range to bypass that block, but in that case the spoofer will not receive response as it will be sent to the spoofed IP. Is there any other way for client/attacker to get a response from such whitelisted website?